# Angular mat-select and webpack module federation event problem

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material, webpack-module-federation

I have two Angular Apps, a shell app and a content app inside a MonoRepo.
The shell app is like a landing page which displays a card and with click on it, the content app is displayed.

Within this content app I am using a mat-select control, which does not close the panel on outside click -> Problem!
It seems that the outside click event is catched by the shell app.
If I use a mat-select within the shell app, everything works fine.

This is my shell webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:4200/",
    uniqueName: "home",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": { eager: true, singleton: true },
        "@angular/common": { eager: true, singleton: true },
        "@angular/router": { eager: true, singleton: true }
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

content webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:4201/",
    uniqueName: "contentModul"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "content",
      library: { type: "var", name: "content" },
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        ContentModule:
          "./projects/content/src/app/content/content.module.ts",
      },
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": { eager: true, singleton: true },
        "@angular/common": { eager: true, singleton: true },
        "@angular/router": { eager: true, singleton: true }
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

and here my routing:

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
    import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./static-pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";
    import { loadRemoteModule } from "./utils/federation-utils";
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
      {
        path: "content",
        loadChildren: () =>
          loadRemoteModule({
            remoteName: "content",
            remoteEntry: "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js",
            exposedModule: "ContentModule",
          }).then((m) => m.ContentModule)
      },
      { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Do you have a clue what´s missing/wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. The problem that I encountered had to do with the imports of an Angular module. I imported Angular's `BrowserModule` in my micro frontends which was wrong. This module should only be imported in your shell application's root module.

The micro frontends should only import `CommonModule` instead. If you import `BrowserModule` instead, this will break the Angular runtime and result in errors like events not being properly catched.

Comment: That wasn't enough for me, I had to add the "@angular/animations" to shared block in both webpack configurations. [mattae's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386392/angular-module-federation-browsermodule/67558647#67558647)