# Angular Module Federation Webpack and Reactive Forms FormControl duplication

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I am creating a microfrontend application using Angular ModuleFederation Application.

I've a reactive form in the 1 micro app

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="email" />

<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="email.hasError('required')">This field is required</span>
```

So, when I run this app `http://localhost:4201/setup` everything works fine with the validation.

After packing this app,

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      
        // For remotes (please adjust)
        name: "businessSetup",
        filename: "businessSetupRemoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
             './BusinessSetupModule': './projects/business-setup/src/app/components/setup/setup.module.ts',
        },        
    
        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
```

When I run the host app `http://localhost:4200`, the micro app loads but there is a weird behavior with the validation. It is duplicating as below and I've no clue.

[image]

**host app webpack**

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      
      
        // For hosts (please adjust)
         remotes: {
             "businessSetup": "businessSetup@http://localhost:4201/businessSetupRemoteEntry.js",
        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
```

Any clues, please?

**Update:**

This is just not working with the route url changes

Works when the url is

```
http://localhost:4200
```

but not when the url is

```
http://localhost:4200/test
```

Comment: Weird! Maybe also add the forms and reactive forms libs to the shared array as singletons?

Comment: Tried with `'@angular/forms': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },` but still the same issue

Comment: Mmm.. strange. Maybe try some consoles inside the constructors of you components/services to see if anything is loaded more than expected?

Comment: I create a very simple component just with one form control with validation and no other dependencies and still the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `"@angular/animations`. Followed the below steps and the issue gone.

1. Added `"@angular/animations": {singleton: true, eager: true}` in both the remotes and the shell app.
2. Removed `BrowserAnimationsModule` in all the modules except in all `app.modules`
3. No need to share `@angular/platform-browser/animations`

[Angular Module Federation BrowserModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386392/angular-module-federation-browsermodule)